# C++11 option only seems to work for main.cpp

Tags: qt, c++11

I created a console application and have put this line in the `.pro` file:

```
CONFIG += c++11
```

Problem: if I use, for instance, `std::to_string()` in *main.cpp*, I have no problem, but if I create a new file/class (with QtCreator IDE) and I put `to_string()` in the class then I have a error that says that I have to use C++11. So it seems like the C++11 option only applies to *main.cpp*.

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: Could you provide exact code of your class and exact compiler error message?

Comment: Is the new file included in yout project?

Comment: Try cleaning your project, then compiling from the command line (just use `qmake` followed by `make` in your project folder) and, finally, update your question with the output of `make`.

Comment: Show the whole .pro file. If you use multiple pro files tied together with “SUBDIRS”, you need the CONFIG+=c++11 in each .pro file that lists SOURCES/HEADERS. Apart from that, it should be applied to all files listed in the respective .pro file.